# Find the row number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to automate my excel table as much as possible. Currently is working partially but trying to make it completely automated. The formula I am using is,
***="SERVER_"&TEXT((ROW()-2),"00")&"::"&'Sheet 1'!D6***
as you see the final output will be a combination of 4 sections
1st and 3rd are static text SERVER_ & ::
4th section 'Sheet 1'!D6is a reference cell value from another sheet
2nd section TEXT((ROW()-2),"00") is where i am seeking ideas. This example is used in cell F3. So as a result it will 01 and which is correct. But if I add a row above this line, I need to go back to this cell (now it will be F4) and change the formula to TEXT((ROW()-3),"00") to get the desired output "01". After that, I need to drag the corner to get 02, 03, 04 and so on to correct the value in the subsequent cell in F column.
I am looking to replace with formula with a better one that will still give the value "01", will not change if a row is added or deleted and if I drag the corner it will update the value to 02, 03, 04 and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the 4th secion of the draged down formulas all refer to `Sheet 1'!D6`, or should they increment?

Comment: Are you using Excel 365?  If so, you can create a Spill formula that doesn't require dragging down

Comment: Something like `="SERVER_"&TEXT((ROW()-ROW($F$3)+1),"00")&"::"&Sheet1!D6
`.  The only constraint is that if row 3 is deleted the formula will break.  Any other row insert or delete, and it will still work

Comment: @chrisneilsen - your formula is working and it is a great idea about using spill...was in my mind but hasn't been implemented. WIll try it next.

Comment: If you want it more automated the better option is power query take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210897/excel-how-to-split-cells-by-comma-delimiter-into-new-cells/72211471#72211471)

Answer (score -1):

In your question you state that, the formula in question is located in cell F3.

And I believe you're trying always get the value of the cell that is at F1. That's why moving the formula down one row forced you to change from

> ROW()-2

to

> ROW()-3

However, if you always want the value at F1, you can simply use an absolute reference and avoid the calculation altogether:

> ="SERVER_"&TEXT($F$1,"00")&"::"&Sheet1!D6

If you're concerned that inserting a column might shift the formula, then you could just make the row absolute and leave the column relative:

> ="SERVER_"&TEXT(F$1,"00")&"::"&Sheet1!D6